# Its really confusing . Plz help me out . I m a true beliver

Tags: sharia, quran, hadith, prophet-muhammad, sunnah

Can anyone proof that muhammad (pbuh) is just a prophet . Not a scientist ??? The athiest people say that muhammad (pbuh) is a scientist . There is not god . So what is the proof plz help me in this answer to the athiest

Comment: Without enough information like why should Mohammad (peace be upon him) be a scientist it's hard to give an answer. But as a Prophet he had a miracle which was the Quran

Comment: I think those atheist people should give you a proof first of Mohammad (peace be upon him) is a scientist! As Allah says: http://quran.com/2/111

Comment: Muhammad (saw) was illiterate. He was not educated so he had not studied science or anything.

Comment: As written, this looks less like a question about the topic of Islam than it does a call for debating advice; please note that we are not a site for debate and argument (see: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22), nor are we a peer-support group for every topic of potential interest to Muslims (see: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/189/22).

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't matter if you believing Allah to He is greatest. That's related with your faith, if you believe to Allah like this:

Say, "He is Allah , [who is] One, Allah , the Eternal Refuge. He neither begets nor is born, Nor is there to Him any equivalent."
AL-IKHLAS [1-4]

And if Muhammad had made up about Us some [false] sayings, We would have seized him by the right hand; Then We would have cut from him the aorta.
AL-HAQQAH [44-46]

Allah would never allow something to go wrong about his religion

Answer (score -1):

Assalaamu alaikum warehmatullahi wabarakatuhu 
In the name of Allah the most Gracious, the most Merciful

According to the Qur'an, the non-believers used to call Prophet Muhammed a poet, a mad man etc (and the atheists call him a scientist, as you are claiming)

And We have not taught him poetry, nor is it meet for him; it is nothing but a reminder and a plain Quran, (36:69)

Surely they used to behave proudly when it was said to them: There is no god but Allah; And to say: What! shall we indeed give up our gods for the sake of a mad poet? (37:35, 36)

And it is not the word of a poet; little is it that you believe; (69:41)

## Volume 9, Book 92, Number 400 :

Narrated by Ibn Masud
    I was with the Prophet at one of the farms of Medina while he was leaning on a date palm leaf-stalk. He passed by a group of Jews and some of them said to the other, Ask him (the Prophet) about the spirit. Some others said, "Do not ask him, lest he should tell you what you dislike" But they went up to him and said, "O Abal Qasim! Inform us bout the spirit." The Prophet stood up for a while, waiting. I realized that he was being Divinely Inspired, so I kept away from him till the inspiration was over. Then the Prophet said, "(O Muhammad) they ask you regarding the spirit, Say: The spirit its knowledge is with my Lord (i.e., nobody has its knowledge except Allah)" (17.85) (This is a miracle of the Qur'an that all the scientists up till now do not know about the spirit, i.e, how life comes to a body and how it goes away at its death) (See Hadith No. 245, Vol. 6)

And Muhammad is no more than an apostle; the apostles have already passed away before him; if then he dies or is killed will you turn back upon your heels? And whoever turns back upon his heels, he will by no means do harm to Allah in the least and Allah will reward the grateful. (3:144)

Muhammad is not the father of any of your men, but he is the Apostle of Allah and the Last of the prophets; and Allah is cognizant of all things. (33:40)

Muhammad is the Apostle of Allah and those with him..... (48:29)

Qaf. I swear by the glorious Quran (that Muhammad is the Apostle of Allah) (50:1)

Comment: Great answer, because atheists believe in the Quran but don't believe in Allah/Prophet?!

Comment: Atheists don't believe in God itself, they believe that it is nature and not god, they believe that everything already existed and that everything has logic to it. They are more logical than spiritual.

Comment: Which is why I gave you a -1. He is asking for something to prove to Atheists and everything you have is from the Quran!

Comment: It is obvious that Atheists don't believe in Allah himself then why would they ask if Muhammed is a Scientist or a Prophet? They would believe in non. And I took references from Qur'an to prove that Muhammed is only a 'Prophet' and no more, many claimed him as mentioned in my answer, if you only read carefully before marking something.

Answer (score -3):

Just tell them 'we' muslims believe that Mohamed is a prophet.

Comment: Neither the question nor this comment is constructive